# Android: space between Expandable ListView Groups

Tags: android, expandablelistview

How can I add an extra `space` between an `expandable listview groups` just like in the below image and that space should also remain in case of no item.

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Try this,

```
        <ExpandableListView
        android:id="@+id/lvExp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:dividerHeight="Your desired height"
        android:divider="Your desired color"/>
```

Comment: tried this but it gives me black color between that space what to do now?

Comment: @Zahid It also add margin between child item. I don't want divider height between child items.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this example would helps you..

> [ExpandableListView - How to set divider only between parent elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6694939/expandablelistview-how-to-set-divider-only-between-parent-elements)

Comment: seen this post but this does not meet my requirements.

Comment: add margin for parent group layout in xml file..i think it would sove problem

Comment: tried this but it only increases the first group height